# Too many output arguments -- symbolic function use issue?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to apply this code https://stackoverflow.com/a/31083592 on my own computer, but I obtain the following error [Too many Output Arguments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TnDk.png)

I do not see why this is since the function is to output two variables T and Y which is defined in the code. Could anyone explain why I get this error?

My input is

```
syms t y
[T, Y] = taylor(t*y, 0, 1, 2, 100); 
plot(T,Y)
```

and my error is

```
Error using sym/taylor
Too many output arguments.
```

Comment: In the example in your link, the user defines a taylor.m Matlab function. It seems like you are just using the built-in taylor function in the matlab symbolic toolbox. https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/taylor.html

Comment: Ah, so matlab was confusing my function name with an already built-in function for the taylor series. Is that it? I changed the function name to something else, `taytay`, and then the code ran: https://i.imgur.com/zReTn58.png Was that the reason for the error?

Comment: Yea, take a look at Maltab's [Function Precedance Order](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/function-precedence-order.html)